# XSLT Transform of Unicode source

Tags: python, xslt, unicode

In my application I am using the [4Suite.org XSLT library](http://4suite.org/docs/CoreManual.xml#xslt_engine) to perform transformations of source XML.  The syntax is like this:

```
from Ft.Xml.Xslt import Transform
transformed_xml = Transform(raw_xml, stylesheet)
```

where `raw_xml` and `stylesheet` have been defined elsewhere in my application.  `raw_xml` will be the xml resulting from reading a filehandle opened with the codecs module so the `raw_xml` will be unicode.

The problem is that the Transform() function requires the value of the source xml (`raw_xml` in my example) to be ascii.  It says so in the pydoc and my own program fails with an error along those lines if I try to transform unicode.

Is there a different approach or is there another python library which can perform an XSLT transformation against a unicode source?  Or, am I misunderstanding something about XSLT transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `Transform` actually needs *ascii* -- looks to me like it should support any encoded Python str. What happens if you call `Transform(raw_xml.encode('utf8'), stylesheet)` (and then decode the resulting utf8-encoded string back to Unicode when you're done processing it of course, if you need Unicode) -- doesn't that work?

Comment: This looks like it did the trick.  I'm having it tested now but it seems promising.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are likely better off using the more modern and actively maintained [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html#xslt).

Comment: I would *love* to use lxml but my application is already distributed at over a hundred sites so I don't have a lot of flexibility in swapping out the xml library.  It could be done but is something I'm going to try to avoid right now.  Now, if I ever get a shot at updating and refactoring this code then, yes, I will probably switch to lxml for ease of use and compatibility with etree.